# How to merge data in csv files

Tags: python

```
def option2():

    f1 = open("C:\\Users\\notis\\Desktop\\data\\input_data2.txt",'r')
    f1c = f1.read()

    f2 = open("C:\\Users\\notis\\Desktop\\data\\input_names.txt",'r')
    f2c = f2.read()

    f3 = open("C:\\Users\\notis\\Desktop\\data\\output_merged_data.txt",'w') # open in `w` mode to write
    f3.write(f1_contents +'\n'+  f2_contents) # concatenate the contents

    h = open("C:\\Users\\notis\\Desktop\\data\\output_merged_data.txt",'r+')
    hc=h.read()

    for lines in f1:
        for lines in f2:
            split_1 = f1c.split()
            split_2 = f2c.split()
            split_3 = hc.split()
            name1 = split_1[0]
            name2 = split_2[0]
            #if split_3 == '':
                #name3 = ''
            #else name3==split_3[0]:
                #name3 = split_3[0]

        if (name1 != name3 , name2 != name3):
            if name1 == name2:

                index = inputNames.index(',')
                newstr = input2[:-1] + inputNames[index:]
                h.write(newstr)
            else:

                if name1 < name2:
                    h.writelines(input2)
                else:
                    h.writelines(inputNames)

                input2 = f.readline()
                inputNames = g.readline()
```

Read files “input_data2.txt” and “input_names.txt” from folder “data” and create a single file merging this data – “output_merged_data.txt”. Each line in the created file is to be unique based on the name (first column of each input file). So if the name is present in the both input files, the rest of the data has to be merged

```
“input_data2.txt”               “input_names.txt”
John, 12.3, abcd                Adam, 121 station road, London
Johnny, 53.3, star              John, Brecon house, Pontypridd
Steve, 33.5, qwer               

Output: “output_merged_data.txt”
Adam, 121 station road, London
John, 12.3, abcd, Brecon house, Pontypridd
Johnny, 53.3, star
Steve, 33.5, qwer
```

This is what it's supposed to do, but it seems that it only merges the two files together, what did I do wrong?

Comment: sorry, first time 'successfully' posting here. A friend tried to help me and told me to add these    #if split_3 == '':
                                    #name3 = ''
                              #else name3==split_3[0]:

to be correct, with those it brings a syntax error, without those, it just merges the two files but it wont replace the line with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be adding a third file (concatenation of the first and second ones) that is only complicating matters and not helping you at all.. the way I see your problem, you would need a dictionary where each person's name is a key, and the attributes associated with them form a list of values. this way if an entry already exists (from reading the first file) you can simply append the additional items to that list.

something like:

```
names = {}
with open('input_data2.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        items = line.split(',')
        name = items[0]  #first element of list
        data = items[1:] #rest of the list
        names[name] = data

with open('input_names.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        items = line.split(',')
        name = items[0]  #first element of list
        data = items[1:] #rest of the list
        if name in names: #if name already exists
            names[name].append(data) #append additional data
        else:
            names[name] = data #create new entry

with open('output_merged_data.txt', 'w') as f:
    for name in names.keys(): #for each entry
        f.write(name + ','.join(names[name])+ '\n') #write a line
```

Note: Your provided code has many structural and syntax errors... More than I can go over in a short post. You would likely benefit reading up on how different data types in python act when you do different things to them. there are tons of great websites that have small code challenges to help you progressively learn how to do the basics, and eventually combine them together to get more complicated things like this problem

Comment: Looks like it will accomplish the stated task of merging the data. However, even though the OP never mentions it, a potential problem with using a dictionary is that the ordering of both input files is lost and the names in merged file will likely be different (and no longer sorted by name as shown in the example input and output).

Comment: @martineau he's got a few other problems to solve before he gets there... alphabetic order however would be easily solved with adding a `sorted()` around `names.keys()` in the writeback section. preserving specific ordering could be added with `from collections import OrderedDict`.